# Any public database of all political entities throughout history?

Tags: historiography

Some possible candidates I found online:

- Wikipedia, grouped by century: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_political_entities_in_the_1st_century
- http://dataforhistory.org/?

But unfortunately nothing serious.

Ideally, it would be an organized database, which some basic relationship between these countries.

If it's only limited to a certain period in history, it'd help too.

Comment: I think the hierarchy of categories on Wikipedia is probably the best dataset for such a general question, but you'll need to find a recursive means of querying it to see contents of subcategories.

Comment: Such an effort would seem, as a British football announcer would put it "a bit ambitious".